# how many linearly independed vectors combinations may I extract from a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Consider the set of $n$ vectors $\mathcal{S}=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$, with $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let that set generate a subspace $\mathbb{V}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $r\le n$. How many different unordered basis of  $\mathbb{V}$ may be constructed by picking up $r$ vectors from $\mathcal{S}$. There is a method to find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the vectors. It might be that any set of $r$ vectors will be linearly  independent, in which case there are $\binom nr$ possibilities. Or it might be that $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ are linearly independent and all the rest are just copies of $v_1$, in which case there are $n-r+1$ possibilities. Even worse, we might have $v_{r+1}=\cdots=v_n=0$, and then there is only one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the vecotrs $v_i$. You could just calculate one basis $B$ of $\mathbb V$ with elements out of $S$, then calculate the coordinates of the remaining vecotrs in $S$ in terms of $B$. Now you can exchange any vector $v$ from B with a remaining vector $w$, as long as the $v$-coordinate of $w$ isn't $0$ and still end up with a basis $B'$. Now you can count.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your scalar field. If your scalar field is infinite, then you can construct infinitely many bases. The reason for this is that given a basis $B$, you can construct a basis $B^\prime$ by replacing $b\in B$ with $b^\prime=\alpha\cdot b$ (where $\alpha\neq 0$ is an element from your field).

In your case, your field is $\mathbb R$, which is infinite. So the answer to your question is *infinitely many*.

Comment: The question is asking which subsets of the given set of vectors $S$ are bases.